# Anyway to debug react-select dropdown from the browser devtools?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm mostly interested in seeing the class names used so I can override them. Problem is, as soon as I click anywhere, even on the dev tools, the drop-down gets removed from the DOM, so there's no way to inspect it.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the classNames straight off the [source:](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/src/Select.js)

Main element:

```
let className = classNames('Select', this.props.className, {
            'has-value': valueArray.length,
            'is-clearable': this.props.clearable,
            'is-disabled': this.props.disabled,
            'is-focused': this.state.isFocused,
            'is-loading': this.props.isLoading,
            'is-open': isOpen,
            'is-pseudo-focused': this.state.isPseudoFocused,
            'is-searchable': this.props.searchable,
            'Select--multi': this.props.multi,
            'Select--rtl': this.props.rtl,
            'Select--single': !this.props.multi,
        });
```

You can get the menu classnames from there as well.